# Force refresh of client's java cache.

Tags: apache-2.2, java, oracle-11g

I have an Oracle Application server that has been upgraded. It serves users a java file which they launch in their browser. After the upgrade user's browsers are still pulling the old java file from their local cache and receiving an error. If a user clears their java cache things will work correctly.

There has got to be a way to tell clients that they need to get the new java file rather then using their local cached version.

Comment: Relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261169/how-to-force-a-java-applet-to-load-out-of-cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm for Java applet caching is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/applet_caching.html).

Try getting Apache to return reasonable `Last-Modified` headers.  If this is not happening, this could mess up the caching algorithm.  `Last-Modified` should be a later date than the previous applet.

Also check that the MIME type for the JAR files from Apache are `application/java-archive`, as not having this can mess up caching (but usually this [prevents them from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694069/java-applet-not-caching)).

There is also the option of making changes to the HTML files as described.

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to change the link that users click to open the java file?  If so, there are a couple of ways to fix it there:

- change `appname.jar` to `appname.jar?version=20120124`.
- add  `<param name="cache_option" value="no">` between `<object>` and `</object>`.  (This will cause clients to reload the latest version every time, not just once.)